# sed with loop to replace certain fields in a file with delimiter :

Tags: shell, sed, while-loop

How should I use the `sed` command to replace certain fields with delimiter `:` and run a check to make sure that the user's input can be found within the file & if it can't be found it will loop again.

```
main_menu                                           #function main_menu
echo "1) choice 1"
echo "2) choice 2"
read choice                                         #read user choice on which choice he wants

if [ $choice -eq 1 ]
then
    edit_item                                              #function
    read $choice_e                                         #read input
    grep -iqs "$choice_e: " Item.txt && echo "item found"  #search file to find match
    while [[ ! ${choice_e} =~ ^([Item.txt])$ ]]; do        #loop to find if input matches search  
        echo "New Title: "                                 #input new 
        read choice_n
        sed -i 's/^/"$choice_n"\t/' Item.txt               #edit the item 
    done
    edit_item                                       
else
    echo "error"                                           #return user to input again
fi
```

Comment: don't see any reference to a delimiter in your code. Is it the choice_n that should be surrounde by delimiter or part of it ? Give maybe a sample of data before and result expected.

Comment: Please learn to indent your code so that it is somewhat comprehensible!

Answer (score 1):

The invocation of `sed` is flawed because of the single quotes mixed with double quotes:

```
sed -i 's/^/"$choice_n"\t/'
```

The single quotes mean that the `$` (and double quotes) are not interpreted by the shell.  What you're probably after is:

```
sed -i "s/^/$choice_n\t/"
```

Without knowing exactly which shell and version of `sed` you're using, it isn't clear whether the `\t` sequence will be translated to a tab or not.  In Bash, you could use the [ANSI C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism:

```
sed -i "s/^/$choice_n"$'\t'/
```

I don't see where your 'delimiter `:`' is coming into play at all.